# Creating a table with descriptives statistics in r

Tags: r

I have a data with multiple variables with diferents categories (integers and factors).

My objective is to create an output with the descriptives statistics, such as:

- for the integer variables only show the mean and the standard deviation
- and for the factor variables show the frequencies

there are a simple scrip to do that?

Thanks
Romeu

Comment: When you are talking about data, is a one data.frame or data.table or each one is separate variable ?

Comment: `summary` will give you something close.

Comment: it's a data.frame.

I use this to put in r

read.csv("C:/Users/Eventos/Desktop/ROMEU/Trabalhos/Estatística/dr_gustavo/1993_2013_originar_l.csv", header=T, sep="\t", na.strings="NA")

Comment: I know, but i have a data with 115 columns for 6665 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do following..

```
colNames = colnames(df)
res = list()
for(i in colNames){
  res[[i]] = switch(class(df[,i]),
         numeric={
           list(mean=mean(df[,i]),sd=sd(df[,i]))
         },
         factor={
           list(table(df[,i]))
         })
}
```

I have just given rough path, you can change according to your use. And create a table the way you want to make.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **stat.desc** function in the `pastecs` package.
If df is your data set, then

```
desc_stats <- stat.desc(df[,c("col1","col2",....)])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you asked for:

```
stat <- function(x) {
  sd <-  if(is.numeric(x))  sd(x) 
  mean <-  if(is.numeric(x)) mean(x)
  Freq <- if(is.factor(x)) table(x)
  z <- rbind(sd, mean, Freq)
  return(z)
}

lapply(df, function(x) stat(x))       #assuming your data.frame is called df
```

Example output:

```
$Category
     A E G I K L M N Q S
Freq 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

$n
         [,1]
sd   43780.01
mean 72845.50

$test
        [,1]
sd   3.02765
mean 5.50000
```

The output is based on this df:

```
df <- structure(list(Category = structure(c(2L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 
10L, 3L, 8L, 9L), .Label = c("A", "E", "G", "I", "K", "L", "M", 
"N", "Q", "S"), class = "factor"), n = c(163051L, 127133L, 106680L, 
64868L, 49701L, 47387L, 47096L, 45601L, 40056L, 36882L), test = 1:10), .Names = c("Category", "n", "test"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "data.frame")
```